# Regexp how to set any number of characters but '|' is required?

Tags: regex, go

This is the string:

```
[randstr: sdfsdfds|dsfsdf sdfds 43rew|fds, 1-1]
```

This string may occurs in a text. This is my regexp I try:

```
`\[(randstr|randstrFixed):(\s+)?\|(.+)(\s+)?,(\s+)?[\d]+-[\d]+]`
```

The main goal to set to the pattern that: `sdfsdfds|dsfsdf sdfds 43rew|fds` - here may be any chars but at least one '|' is required. Such requirement because in text may occur another similar string like `[randstr: A-Z, 2-4]`

More explanation:

https://regex101.com/r/1BNzA4/2/ - here is example text and regexp from @Wiktor Stribiżew

There u can text is changed, now the 'pattern' begins from `[->` so in regexp I have to tell it that `[->` must mot occur.

Comment: Do you mean you want ``\[(randstr(?:Fixed)?):\s*[^][|]*\|[^][]*,\s*\d+-\d+]``? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffJJVF/1).

Comment: yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if you need any capturing groups. Do you need to get any sub-value after you get  a  match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, here I don't need capturing grroups. Just find hole match by regexp.

Comment: Ok, then I removed the extra grouping from my pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\[randstr(?:Fixed)?:\s*[^][|]*\|[^][]*,\s*\d+-\d+]
```

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffJJVF/2)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `randstr(?:Fixed)?` - `randstr`  or `randstrFixed`
- `:\s*`  - a colon and 0+ whitespaces
- `[^][|]*` - 0+ chars other than `[`, `]` and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `,\s*` - a comma and 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+-\d+` - 1+ digits, `-`, 1+ digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Great explanation. And one more question on a topic: like u did `[^][|]` - that means `[` and `[` and `|` must not occur. But how can I set char combination to not occur, i.e.  `[=>` - how to set this must not occur ?

Comment: @Mikael It is not possible in Go regex because it does not support lookarounds. You could probably do with a 2-char combination though, but it would look like a hack.

Comment: Can u please give an example? I might be very helpful and needed for me..

Comment: @Mikael Sorry, I am not sure of this requirement. Could you please share a regex101 link with a couple of examples? Again, the match should occur only when the string is like `[randstr:....]`, but there must be at least one occurrence of a  `->` substring?

Comment: yes I have updated my post. I hope it is understandable.. The task is if text begins with `[randstr: .|-|/, 1-1]` - it must not capture all text, but here `.|-|/` I also want have `[` this. So this is why I changed `[randstr` to `[->randstr`.

Comment: @Mikael So, you want `\[->randstr(?:Fixed)?:\s*[^][|]*\|[^][]*,\s*\d+-\d+<-]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BNzA4/3))?

Comment: yes but now I need tel to regexp like `[->` - this must not occur, like u did with `[^]\[|]`. But u said go doesn't support it ((

Comment: What are your expected matches?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/SZU1Sw/1 please take a look, I want it to catch exactly first `[->randstr: .|-|]|/, 1-1<-]`  And for this I think I need tell it that `[->` must not occur

Comment: @Mikael It seems to me you can still rely on the fact that your string starts with `[` char. I suggest keeping just `[` in the negated character class, see `\[->randstr(?:Fixed)?:[^[]*\|[^[]*,\s*\d+-\d+<-]` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZU1Sw/2).

Comment: Please take a look, https://regex101.com/r/SZU1Sw/5  There also possible `[`

Comment: @Mikael I do not feel it is safe, but try `\[->randstr(?:Fixed)?:(?:[^-]|-[^>])*\|(?:[^-]|-[^>])*-?,\s*\d+-\d+<-]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZU1Sw/6)).

Comment: Yeah it works! But what problems it may cause ? U said you don't feel it is safe.. This is my last ask. Thank you!

Comment: @Mikael Because of the `-?` hack I added after the `(?:[^-]|-[^>])*` part. But probably it will not cause any serious side effects.